Es posible inmovilizar una sección de la pagina usando Bootstrap
¿Saben si Bootstrap 3.3.6 tiene alguna clase que permita inmovilizar un div o container dentro de la pagina, de la misma forma que inmovilizamos en Excel una sección de filas de la hoja mientras que todo lo demás se mueve.

Si lo queres hacer con CSS, se utiliza postion ya fixed o 'sticky' (dependiendo el contexto). Más info. Y en esa versión de Bootstrap existe el Affix que puede que sea lo que estas buscando. Si quisieras una respuesta sería necesario que compartas algo de lo has hecho y lo que necesitas lograr.

Gracias por tu comentario,, me sirvió de mucho!. ¿Puedes dejarlo como respuesta para que pueda aceptarlo como solución?

En esa versión de Bootstrap existe el Affix que puede que sea lo que estás buscando.
Ejemplo:


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div data-spy="affix">
        <p>Columna fija</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus bibendum ut nibh malesuada lacinia. Nulla in lacinia diam, et tristique felis. Nam at commodo lorem. Pellentesque vel mattis sapien. Pellentesque et nisi eget purus maximus bibendum
        sit amet nec ex. Morbi sem nunc, molestie sit amet pharetra eget, aliquet in eros. Vivamus quam massa, viverra non quam in, suscipit viverra leo. Phasellus aliquet mi lectus, in ultricies purus fermentum auctor. Phasellus sollicitudin accumsan
        ligula a rutrum.</p>

      <p>Vivamus euismod sem nisl, in volutpat velit molestie ac. Duis elit magna, ullamcorper ac ultrices eu, pulvinar quis enim. Nullam pellentesque, purus in tempus pretium, tellus ante gravida sapien, ut sodales nisl turpis in massa. Sed maximus magna
        lacinia aliquam tempor. Praesent egestas sem nisl. Proin at eleifend lacus. Cras at malesuada nibh, sit amet posuere turpis. Maecenas tristique nec ipsum et ornare. Ut volutpat porta augue eget pulvinar. Vestibulum ut dui non lacus maximus commodo
        pellentesque pharetra ligula.</p>

      <p>Fusce suscipit tempus condimentum. Mauris congue dignissim odio imperdiet tincidunt. Fusce varius suscipit imperdiet. Morbi facilisis nisi felis, sit amet congue purus ultrices quis. Etiam sit amet libero mi. In bibendum viverra ex sed faucibus.
        Suspendisse convallis dui sit amet facilisis sollicitudin. Etiam volutpat elit at nulla congue, eget molestie ex vestibulum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer luctus, velit ac ultricies
        laoreet, lorem felis posuere urna, et vehicula nulla ligula id eros.</p>

      Sed ac ex aliquam, rhoncus velit in, tempor odio. Mauris in tortor eget est bibendum lacinia et sed orci. Nunc faucibus ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at eleifend diam, quis sagittis quam. Integer semper luctus risus a faucibus. Donec pulvinar ante eget
      augue finibus fermentum. Cras fermentum est tellus, vitae malesuada sem dapibus in. Quisque pulvinar eu libero in blandit. Etiam ac diam semper, feugiat justo fringilla, elementum dui. Pellentesque ac quam imperdiet, gravida augue sed, pharetra
      metus. Phasellus cursus nunc massa, quis consequat ante feugiat non. Mauris pellentesque mauris id erat eleifend, id aliquam nisl rutrum. Maecenas magna massa, dignissim at sem vitae, lacinia blandit sapien. Suspendisse molestie condimentum ante,
      nec ullamcorper massa. Cras nunc purus, pulvinar lobortis dui sed, vestibulum tincidunt orci. Sed sed gravida nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean sed ultricies nibh. Aenean tempus
      gravida accumsan. Duis justo neque, ultrices non lectus at, commodo viverra augue. Duis efficitur diam metus, at ultricies lacus egestas non. Pellentesque malesuada accumsan velit, eget feugiat velit tincidunt at. Integer ut elementum eros, eget
      laoreet mi.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Gracias por la información – Marcos!
